# Tekton - maven task - cannot compile with JDK 17

Tags: tekton

Building a project with the Tekton standard "maven" Task works fine for JDK8 and JDK11.

When changing to another JDK17 project, I get this message:

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project quotes: Fatal error compiling: error:
> invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]

The default maven plugin version was 3.10.1.

How can I build with the modern JDK17 in Tekton task Maven?

In the pom.xml I have all settings (and even more then strictly necessary) to ask maven to compile with JDK17:

```
<properties>
  <java.version>17</java.version>
  <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
  <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Optionally I even added the superfluous statements:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.8.1</version>    
             <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard (Tekton Hub) maven task has an optional parameter to set a specific maven-build image.

Just add in the Pipeline the parameter 'MAVEN_IMAGE' as shown below:

```
- name: maven
  taskRef:
    name: maven
  runAfter:
    - fetch-repository
  params:
    - name: GOALS
      value:
        - -Dmaven.repo.local=$(workspaces.maven-settings.path)
        - package
    - name: MAVEN_IMAGE
      value: maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine
```